# Sublime Text autocomplete left column keyboard shortcut

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

The list of Sublime Text autocompletions can have two columns. If I press tab to select an autocompletion, it always uses the right column. What if I want to autocomplete using the left column?

[image: B2JointDef - box2D.dynamics.joints.B2JointDef animation]

This question is not language specific, but for example if I type "B2J" I get the suggestion "B2JointDef - box2D.dynamics.joints.B2JointDef". It's what I want, but I already imported "box2D.dynamics.joints.*" so I just need "B2JointDef". However if I press tab or enter, I get the whole "box2D.dynamics.joints.B2JointDef".

Do I need to use a more intelligent autocomplete package, or is there some way to get the left column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SublimeJEDI](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI). It should know that you have imported the package